# How to pass header with L.GeoJSON.AJAX

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm looking for a way to pass header keys and values. It's not entirely clear how i should do it.

So this is the code, but the X api key part isn't working:

```
  myGeoJsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(geoJsonRequestUrl, {
          dataType: 'json',
          headers: { 'X-Api-Key': '1BMtfBTPzvxZdd4...' },
          attribution: '',
          interactive: true,
          onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
          style: style
 }).addTo(map);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `L.GeoJSON.AJAX` plugin has no option to pass headers to AJAX request. You'll have to use one of the classic `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` or JQuery `$.ajax` methods to fetch the data with custom headers.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Tomazic!

So solved it like this:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "get",
       url: geoJsonRequestUrl,
       headers: { 'X-Api-Key': '1BMtfBTPzvxZdd4...' },
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       success: function (response) {
              myGeoJsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(response, {
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
                    style: style
              }).addTo(map);
       },
  });
```